# Python -- replace/remove _XXX from string

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I am looking to replace _XXX within a given string. XXX is any 3 chars. They can all differ as well.

IE:

```
  path/to_XXX/file  -> path/to/file 

  path/to/file_xxx.java -> path/to/file.java
```

I can use regex or any other solution.

This is with python 3.3.

Comment: _XXX is any character but these three characters would be same chracter right ?

Comment: They could be different. -- Edit made for the fact they could differ

Comment: Understood but the concern is,  It will replace _CBu for the string _CBuchanan

Comment: The pattern is specifically only _XXX, therefore i will never remove more information than needed. 

As for tested code, I am new to python and am still working on the program as a whole and I am also horrid with regex so I i figured why not ask for some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have to use regex then the below solution will work:

```
text1 = 'path/to_ABC/file'
text2 =  'path/to/file_xxx.java'

pat = r'(_[A-Za-z]{3})'

new1 = re.sub(pat,'',text1,re.MULTILINE)
new2 = re.sub(pat,'',text2,re.MULTILINE)

print(new1)
print(new2)

'path/to/file'
'path/to/file.java'
```

Here the `regex` will capture any 3 characters from `A to Z` (Both upper and lower) followed by `'_'` and the [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) will replace them with a blank.

Comment: Thanks this is helpful! I'll be able to test it tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

A regex is not needed for this. You can use Python's `string.replace()` function.

```
>>> path = "path/to_XXX/file"
>>> chars = "_XXX"                  # or whatever string you want to replace
>>> path = path.replace(chars, "")  # replace _XXX with an empty string
>>> path
'path/to/file'
>>>
```

Comment: The problem is the XXX,  they can be any 3 chars. Therefore just using _XXX won't work.

Comment: @CBuchanan Use a variable then

Comment: I edited my answer so the string you want to replace can be kept in a variable

Answer (score 0):

You can simply remove that using `.sub`,

```
import re
regex = r"_\w{3}"
test_str = ("path/to_XXX/file\n\n"
    "path/to/file_xxx.java")

subst = ""

# You can manually specify the number of replacements by changing the 4th argument
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE)

if result:
    print (result)
```

**DEMO:** https://regex101.com/r/15pvJz/2